# How to extract specific words from a string with pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have a dataframe which contains the names of supervisors and advisors of students' dissertations in a faculty as follows for example:

```
 DF<-data.frame(Names=c("Name : Ali , Family : Ahmadi , Type : First supervisor Name : Aram , Family : Rezaeei , Type : Advisor Name : Omid , Family : Saeedi , Type : Advisor 1 Name : Nima , Family : Shaki , Type : Advisor 2 Name : Sohrab , Family : Karimi , Type : Advisor 3",
  "Name : Ali , Family : Ahmadi , Type : First supervisor Name : Aram , Family : Rezaeei , Type : Advisor Name : Omid , Family : Saeedi , Type : Advisor 1 Name : Nima , Family : Shaki , Type : Advisor 2 Name : Sohrab , Family : Karimi , Type : Advisor 3",
  "Name : Ali , Family : Ahmadi , Type : First supervisor Name : Aram , Family : Rezaeei , Type : Advisor Name : Omid , Family : Saeedi , Type : Advisor 1 Name : Nima , Family : Shaki , Type : Advisor 2 Name : Sohrab , Family : Karimi , Type : Advisor 3"))
```

I gonna separate supervisors and advisors as two distinct columns (as my expectation) like this:

```
DF1<-data.frame(Supervisor=c("Ali Ahmadi","Ali Ahmadi","Ali Ahmadi"),Advisors=c("Aram Rezaeei, Omid Saeedi, Nima Shaki, Sohrab Karimi","Aram Rezaeei, Omid Saeedi, Nima Shaki, Sohrab Karimi","Aram Rezaeei, Omid Saeedi, Nima Shaki, Sohrab Karimi"))

DF1
  Supervisor                                             Advisors
1 Ali Ahmadi Aram Rezaeei, Omid Saeedi, Nima Shaki, Sohrab Karimi
2 Ali Ahmadi Aram Rezaeei, Omid Saeedi, Nima Shaki, Sohrab Karimi
3 Ali Ahmadi Aram Rezaeei, Omid Saeedi, Nima Shaki, Sohrab Karimi
```

I tried following codes:

```
DF1<-strsplit(DF$Names, "Name :")

stopwords = c(":","Type","Family","Name","1","2", "3", "Advisor", "Family")

DF2 <- lapply(DF1,function(x) unlist(strsplit(x," ")) )

DF3 <- lapply(DF2,function(x)  x[!x %in% stopwords] )

DF4<-lapply(DF3,function(x)  paste(x, collapse = " "))
```

But the final results as follows is not what was my expectation and apparently need further work to be converted to a datataframe!:

```
DF4
[[1]]
[1] " Ali , Ahmadi , First supervisor  Aram , Rezaeei ,  Omid , Saeedi ,  Nima , Shaki ,  Sohrab , Karimi ,"

[[2]]
[1] " Ali , Ahmadi , First supervisor  Aram , Rezaeei ,  Omid , Saeedi ,  Nima , Shaki ,  Sohrab , Karimi ,"

[[3]]
[1] " Ali , Ahmadi , First supervisor  Aram , Rezaeei ,  Omid , Saeedi ,  Nima , Shaki ,  Sohrab , Karimi ,"
```

Is there any simplified method to solve the problem? I found regexp can be helpful but I don't know how to use it atleast in the case of my example. Thanks in advance for any answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an attempt with `extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
DF %>%
  # clean strings:
  mutate(Names = gsub("\\s?(Name|Family|First supervisor|Advisor|Type|\\d|\\s[,:])", "", Names, perl = TRUE)) %>%
  # extract data into columns:
  extract(Names,
          into = c("Supervisor", "Advisor"),
          regex = "(\\w+\\s\\w+)\\s(.*)") %>%
  # insert commas into `Advisor`:
  mutate(Advisor = gsub("(\\w+\\s\\w+\\b)(?!$)", "\\1,", Advisor, perl = TRUE))
  Supervisor                                              Advisor
1 Ali Ahmadi Aram Rezaeei, Omid Saeedi, Nima Shaki, Sohrab Karimi
2 Ali Ahmadi Aram Rezaeei, Omid Saeedi, Nima Shaki, Sohrab Karimi
3 Ali Ahmadi Aram Rezaeei, Omid Saeedi, Nima Shaki, Sohrab Karimi
```

**Explanation** (as requested by OP):

The regular expression in `extract`'s `regex` expression is designed to do two tasks:

- (i) it must describe the string as a whole, from beginning to end
- (ii) it must pick out those elements that should populate the newly created columns

Task (i) is achieved in that `(\\w+\\s\\w+)` captures the two words that make up the `Supvervisor` name, while `\\s` describes (but does not capture) the following whitespace and `(.*)` describes/matches anything that follows that whitespace - i.e., in this case the four `Advisor` names.

Task (ii) is achieved by wrapping the `Supvervisor` name and the `Advisor` names in **capturing groups** given in parentheses; these parentheses are the 'syntax' by which the function `extract` 'realizes' that their content should go into the new columns.

The commas finally are inserted between the `Advisor` names again using a capturing group, which can be recollected in `gsub`'s replacment argument using backreference (`\\1`). The `(?!$)` expression is a negative lookahead to assert that the comma is to be inserted **only** if what follows the word boundary anchor `\\b`is **not** (hence the `!` in the lookahead) the end of the string (expressed in `$`). Hope this helps!

Data:

```
DF<-data.frame(Names=c("Name : Ali , Family : Ahmadi , Type : First supervisor Name : Aram , Family : Rezaeei , Type : Advisor Name : Omid , Family : Saeedi , Type : Advisor 1 Name : Nima , Family : Shaki , Type : Advisor 2 Name : Sohrab , Family : Karimi , Type : Advisor 3",
                       "Name : Ali , Family : Ahmadi , Type : First supervisor Name : Aram , Family : Rezaeei , Type : Advisor Name : Omid , Family : Saeedi , Type : Advisor 1 Name : Nima , Family : Shaki , Type : Advisor 2 Name : Sohrab , Family : Karimi , Type : Advisor 3",
                       "Name : Ali , Family : Ahmadi , Type : First supervisor Name : Aram , Family : Rezaeei , Type : Advisor Name : Omid , Family : Saeedi , Type : Advisor 1 Name : Nima , Family : Shaki , Type : Advisor 2 Name : Sohrab , Family : Karimi , Type : Advisor 3"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution.

```r
DF <- data.frame(Names=c("Name : Ali , Family : Ahmadi , Type : First supervisor Name : Aram , Family : Rezaeei , Type : Advisor Name : Omid , Family : Saeedi , Type : Advisor 1 Name : Nima , Family : Shaki , Type : Advisor 2 Name : Sohrab , Family : Karimi , Type : Advisor 3",
                       "Name : Ali , Family : Ahmadi , Type : First supervisor Name : Aram , Family : Rezaeei , Type : Advisor Name : Omid , Family : Saeedi , Type : Advisor 1 Name : Nima , Family : Shaki , Type : Advisor 2 Name : Sohrab , Family : Karimi , Type : Advisor 3",
                       "Name : Ali , Family : Ahmadi , Type : First supervisor Name : Aram , Family : Rezaeei , Type : Advisor Name : Omid , Family : Saeedi , Type : Advisor 1 Name : Nima , Family : Shaki , Type : Advisor 2 Name : Sohrab , Family : Karimi , Type : Advisor 3"))

stopwords <- c(":","Type","Family","Name","1","2", "3", "Advisor", "Family")
stoppattern <- paste(stopwords, collapse = "|")

DF1 <- strsplit(DF$Names, "Name :")
DF1 <- lapply(DF1, \(x) trimws(x[sapply(x, nchar) > 0L]))

DF2 <- lapply(DF1, \(x) {
  gsub(stoppattern, "", x)
})

DF3 <- lapply(DF2, \(x) {
  y <- gsub(stoppattern, "", x)
  y <- strsplit(x, ",")
  y <- lapply(y, trimws)
  lapply(y, \(.y) {
    .y <- trimws(.y)
    .y[sapply(.y, nchar) > 0L]
  })
})

DF4 <- lapply(DF3, \(x) {
  Supervisor <- x[[1]][1:2]
  Supervisor <- paste(trimws(Supervisor), collapse = " ")
  Advisors <- unlist(x[-1])
  Advisors <- paste(trimws(Advisors), collapse = ", ")
  data.frame(Supervisor, Advisors)
})

Final <- do.call(rbind, DF4)
Final
#>   Supervisor                                                 Advisors
#> 1 Ali Ahmadi Aram, Rezaeei, Omid, Saeedi, Nima, Shaki, Sohrab, Karimi
#> 2 Ali Ahmadi Aram, Rezaeei, Omid, Saeedi, Nima, Shaki, Sohrab, Karimi
#> 3 Ali Ahmadi Aram, Rezaeei, Omid, Saeedi, Nima, Shaki, Sohrab, Karimi
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Messy Base R:

```
# Store a vector of names: ir_names => character vector
ir_names <- c("Name", "Family", "Type")

# Compute it's lenght: ir_name_len => string scalar
ir_name_len <- length(ir_names)

# Compute the desired result: res => data.frame
res <- do.call(
  rbind, 
  lapply(
    strsplit(
      DF$Names,
      "Name\\s+\\:\\s+"
    ),
    function(x){
      y <- data.frame(tmp = unlist(strsplit(x, " , ")))
      ir1 <- setNames(
        data.frame(
          do.call(
            rbind, 
            lapply(
              split(
                y, 
                ceiling(seq_len(nrow(y))/ir_name_len)
              ), 
              t
            )
          ),
          row.names = NULL,
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        ),
        ir_names
      )
      ir2 <- transform(
        ir1,
        Name = trimws(paste(Name, gsub("Family\\s+\\:\\s+", "", Family))),
        Type = trimws(gsub("Type\\s+\\:\\s+", "", Type))
      )[,c("Name", "Type")]
      ir3 <- data.frame(
        Supervisor = ir2$Name[which(grepl("supervisor", ir2$Type))],
        Advisor = toString(ir2$Name[-which(grepl("supervisor", ir2$Type))]),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
        row.names = NULL
      )
    }
  )
)
# Print to console: data.frame => stdout(console)
res
```